# How to add content to overlay frame in google maps for ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, overlay

I have added a fly-in overlay with a toggle button like the one shown in the google maps sdk sample. I cannot find out how to add content to the frame and need to add a title/name area and then a description box below. I was wondering how to do this, or if there is another way I should do it.

Here is the sdk sample from above: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/code-samples

Here is the code for my MapViewController.m

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

static CGFloat kOverlayHeight = 180.0f;

@implementation MapViewController {
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
    UIView *_overlay;

    __strong IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *_flyInButton;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:39.901379 //Tony X
                                                            longitude:-105.007308 //Tony Y
                                                                 zoom:18];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView_.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, kOverlayHeight, 0);
    mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;

    self.view = mapView_;

    _flyInButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Toggle Overlay"
                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                   target:self
                                                   action:@selector(didTapFlyIn)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = _flyInButton;

    CGRect overlayFrame = CGRectMake(0, -kOverlayHeight, 0, kOverlayHeight);
    _overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:overlayFrame];
    _overlay.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    _overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.0 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.0 alpha:0.9];
    [self.view addSubview:_overlay];





    /*GMSMarker *markerCaleb = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    markerCaleb.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.900747, -105.00773400000003); //Caleb X, Caleb Y
    markerCaleb.title = @"Caleb's House";
    markerCaleb.snippet = @"Denver, CO";
    markerCaleb.map = mapView_; */


    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *markerTony = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    markerTony.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.901379, -105.007308); //Tony X, Tony Y
    markerTony.title = @"Mr. Tony's House";
    markerTony.snippet = @"Denver, CO";
    markerTony.map = mapView_;
}

- (void)didTapFlyIn {
    UIEdgeInsets padding = mapView_.padding;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
        if (padding.bottom == 0.0f) {
            _overlay.frame = CGRectMake(0, size.height - kOverlayHeight, size.width, kOverlayHeight);
            mapView_.padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, kOverlayHeight, 0);
        } else {
            _overlay.frame = CGRectMake(0, mapView_.bounds.size.height, size.width, 0);
            mapView_.padding = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        }
    }];
}



@end
```

Here is a visual of what I want: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1ybeqXEQrmTZzFmSAOpHgVlIUbew1i55vVJIRNktGf-0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!